# Why git push --quiet produce output?

Tags: git

I'm doing git push with a quiet flag and expect that git will not produce any messages. The documentation says

> **--quiet** Suppress all output, including the listing of updated refs, unless an error occurs. Progress is not reported to the standard error
>   stream.

but I still receive "Branch develop....". Why is that?

```
> $ git status 
> On branch develop
> Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
> nothing to commit, working directory clean
> 
> $ git push --set-upstream origin develop --quiet
> Branch develop set up to track remote branch develop from origin.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the `--set-upstream` that is producing that message. The `push` is totally quiet.  `--set-upstream` is effectively a call-out to `git branch -u upstream/foo`. If you want `git branch` to be silent, you will need to call it yourself, with its own `--quiet` option.

Answer (score 2):

"[`git` push `--quiet` --set-upstream``](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a819e2b3ef7c27d04befa0a345c9e6e3c7a7965e/Documentation/git-push.txt#L386)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt--q))</sup> was not, indeed, quiet when setting the upstream branch configuration.

That has been corrected with Git 2.32 (Q2 2021).

See [commit f3cce89](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f3cce896a8e14e4732f45a6ee46f77e7ed17a990) (15 Apr 2021) by [Øystein Walle (`Osse`)](https://github.com/Osse).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a819e2b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a819e2b3ef7c27d04befa0a345c9e6e3c7a7965e), 30 Apr 2021)</sup>

> ### [`transport`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f3cce896a8e14e4732f45a6ee46f77e7ed17a990): respect verbosity when setting upstream
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Øystein Walle</sup>

> A command such as [`git push`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f3cce896a8e14e4732f45a6ee46f77e7ed17a990/Documentation/git-push.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push))</sup> -qu origin feature will print "Branch 'feature' set up to track remote branch 'feature' from 'origin'." even when `--quiet` is passed.
> In this case it's because `install_branch_config()` is always called with `BRANCH_CONFIG_VERBOSE`.
>
> `struct transport` keeps track of the desired verbosity.
> Fix the above issue by passing `BRANCH_CONFIG_VERBOSE` conditionally based on that.

This should now be actually quiet:

```
git push --quiet -u --no-progress upstream main
```